# Continuity And Infinite Limits

Tags: calculus

Does there exists a continuous function $f(x)$ such that if $x$ approaches infinity by taking a sequence of value say $a_n$ then $f(x)$ approaches $L$ and when $x$ approaches infinity by taking a sequence of values say $b_n$ then $f(x)$ approaches infinity? If yes give an example or if no then prove it?
$$$$Can Someone plz help me regarding this question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x):= x(\cos (\pi x) + 1)$. Then $f(a_n) = 0$ for $a_n = 2n+1$, so $a_n \to \infty$ and $f(a_n) \to 0$. Also $f(b_n) = b_n$ for $b_n = 2n$. So $b_n \to \infty$ and so $f(b_n) \to \infty$.

Comment: Also can you plz explain that whether the integral $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx$$ of such functions converges or not? If yes then give an example and if no prove it??

Comment: This is a separate question. Ask a new question if you want an answer. The guidelines suggest one question per post. It's worth noting the function I gave here will not have a convergent integral (you should try to convince yourself of that). You can try to come up with some function s.t. it has a convergent integral and has the property in this post. One should exist.

Comment: If the question asked in this post has been resolved, please mark the answer as accepted.